# AngularJS custom component - undefined binding

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

Coding a custom component in AngularJS to which I want to pass an attribute called "parentview".

My code is as follows.

The console.log() of 'parentview' in the controller of my component displays "undefined"... I don't understand why. Especially given that 'user' and 'limit' are well displayed.

Any clue ?

Thanks

dashboard.html

```
<div>
    <suggested-sessions user="user" limit="3" parentview='Dash'></suggested-sessions>
</div>
```

suggestedSessions component:

```
component('suggestedSessions', {
  bindings: {
    user: '<',
    limit: '<',
    parentview: '<'
  },
  template:
  `
    <div class="padding-container">
    <session-item-by-id ng-repeat="group in $ctrl.groups | orderBy:'preview.timestamp'" group=group limit="3" parentview="$ctrl.parentview"></session-item-by-id>
    </div>
  `,
  controller: function($q, $timeout, GroupService) {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      console.log('parent view: ', this.parentview);
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: What if you put your console.log(...) directly in your controller, I mean not in the function $onInit but outside of it ?

Comment: Same thing. Actually I was doing it before and changed to $onInit because I though that was the problem... but no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding your strings using `@` instead of `<`.

```
bindings: {
    user: '@',
    limit: '<',
    parentview: '@'
},
```

From the [AngularJS Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) documentation:

> @ bindings can be used when the input is a string, especially when the value of the binding doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pass a string I think you need add extra quotes

JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/mmqag91q/1/)

```
 <div>
   <suggested-sessions user="user" limit="3" parentview='"Dash"'></suggested-
    sessions>

 </div>
```